# Want to generate xy graph from 2 wave graph in J2EE (from MySQL DB)

Tags: java, jquery, json, jakarta-ee

1. I will have to create two columns in MYSQL database and insert data in that, each column contain 8-9 k data.
2. Then i need to plot this data in chosen GUI in three separate plots on one screen as shown in attached image.
3. Time interval for X-axis for plotting individual graph is 0.001.
4. Then i need to plot these two waveform data against each other as XY graph as shown in graph.

How to achieve this using j2ee because the condition is that xy graph should appear within 2 or 3 second

Regards, 
Prashant

Comment: java-ee and jequery are quite often contradictory. If you want to do it on the server, use java-ee and java. Don't use jason for the graphic though. If you want to do it on the client use jquery and get the data with json or xml.  Can you give us a data sample?

Comment: Only 2 column ( Contain data in number format for e.g 1,2,3 etc) in MySQL Database table 1st is for wave 1st and 2nd is for 2nd wave and we want to generate XY chart from this two column

Comment: Is using java-ee a hard condition? Do you already have the server running?

Comment: Yes we have server running , How to achieve that????

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty incomplete and only a pointer in the general direction.
The solution consists of three steps:

1. **Getting the data from the database.**
   There are basically two options here:

   1. use simple SQL using JDBC
   2. use JPA

   I assume you already have knowledge of that, if not there are many tutorials on both topics.
2. **Creating a graph using java.** 
   I suggest using http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html but there are probably alternatives. In this scenario you would want to render to an (temporary) image file.
   You will need to play around to find the actual graph you like.
3. **Sending the graph to the browser.**
   Sadly I currently don't know how to do that.